# getting the ng-object selected with ng-change

Tags: angularjs

Given the following select element

```
<select ng-options="size.code as size.name for size in sizes " 
        ng-model="item.size.code" 
        ng-change="update(MAGIC_THING)">
</select>
```

Is there a way to get MAGIC_THING to be equal to the currently selected size, so I have access to `size.name` and `size.code` in my controller?

size.code affects a lot of the other parts of the app (image urls, etc), but when the ng-model of `item.size.code` is updated, `item.size.name` needs to be updated as well for the user facing stuff. I assume that the correct way to do this is capturing the change event and setting the values inside of my controller, but I'm not sure what I can pass into update to get the proper values.

If this is completely the wrong way to go about it, I'd love to know the right way.

Answer (score 502, accepted):

Instead of setting the ng-model to item.size.code, how about setting it to size:

```
<select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes" 
   ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
```

Then in your `update()` method, `$scope.item` will be set to the currently selected item.

And whatever code needed `item.size.code`, can get that property via `$scope.item.code`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/G8S32/).

**Update** based on more info in comments:

Use some other $scope property for your select ng-model then:

```
<select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes" 
   ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update()"></select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.update = function() {
   $scope.item.size.code = $scope.selectedItem.code
   // use $scope.selectedItem.code and $scope.selectedItem.name here
   // for other stuff ...
}
```

Comment: If I set my model as item, how do I preselect a value?

Comment: Put this inside your `<select>`: ng-init="item=sizes[0]"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't think I have shared enough of the situation. 

item is a object that is created page load.
the sizes array of objects comes in on user interaction with an edit button, so if I do this it will override the entire item object. I need a way to create a bunch of options in a select box that preselects a value from a completely separate part of the data object.

Comment: I don't understand how - $scope.item.size.code = selectedItem.code would work, how can you just ref selectedItem without $scope in update function?

Comment: Is this true? It seems that ng-change handler is fired before the ng-model is updated, so trying $scope.item.size.code = $scope.selectedItem.code might not always give you the updated model value. Has anyone seen that when using ng-change?

Comment: Guess there's nothing stopping you from doing this either: `ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update(selectedItem)"`

Comment: select box is not getting dismissed after selection, and the selection is only happening if i click outside the select box. Why is this happening? i am facing this issue only on ios platform, on android its fine.

Answer (score 47):

You can also directly get selected value using following code

```
 <select ng-options='t.name for t in templates'
                  ng-change='selectedTemplate(t.url)'></select>
```

script.js

```
 $scope.selectedTemplate = function(pTemplate) {
    //Your logic
    alert('Template Url is : '+pTemplate);
}
```

Comment: This answer the question while the accepted one gives an alternative

Comment: where do you initialize or get template variable?

Comment: @KatLimRuiz You can initialize variable base on your requirement.In my code it's initialize in current controller.You can also initialize in parent controller or root controller of your application.

Comment: oh ok, so basically template would be kind of the object being modified by the form, ok.

Comment: Does this work without specifying a model? I get this error: Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'select', can't be found!

Comment: ngModel is definitely required for select elements, according to the documentation. The other directives are optional, but that one is not.

Comment: I hate to say it but this is one of the scenarios where I'm thinking the jQuery, ajax way of doing things makes way more sense

Comment: This does not work! ng-change does not have access to temporary variable (t) created inside ng-options.

Comment: Why does this have 59 upvotes? @Garbage is right. This simply does not work.

Comment: This is the exact problem OP is having and you posted it as a solution haha.

Answer (score 16):

you also coud try this:

```
<select  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="update()">
   <option ng-repeat="item in items" 
         ng-selected="selectedItem == item.Id" value="{{item.Id}}">
      {{item.Name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This solution is good if you need to format the value. Using just the Select approach I couldn't format the value easily.

Answer (score 8):

If Divyesh Rupawala's answer doesn't work (passing the current item as the parameter), then please see the `onChanged()` function in this Plunker.  It's using `this`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/B5TDQJ

Answer (score 2):

```
<select ng-model="item.size.code">
<option ng-repeat="size in sizes" ng-attr-value="size.code">{{size.name}}          </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat in a select.

Comment: @JepserBernardino sometime you need finer access to <option>, e.g. to style some special/default options regardless whether they are selected or not

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Javascript
$scope.update = function () {
    $scope.myItem;
    alert('Hello');
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div class="form-group">
     <select name="name"
             id="id" 
             ng-model="myItem" 
             ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes"
             class="form-control" 
             ng-change="update()"
             multiple
             required>
     </select>
</div>
```

İf you want to write, name, id, class, multiple, required , You can write in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some ideas

.NET C# View Model

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

.NET C# Web Api Controller

```
public class DepartmentController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var sms = Ctx.Departments;

        var vms = new List<DepartmentViewModel>();

        foreach (var sm in sms)
        {
            var vm = new DepartmentViewModel()
            {
                Id = sm.Id,
                Name = sm.DepartmentName
            };
            vms.Add(vm);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vms);
    }

}
```

Angular Controller:

```
$http.get('/api/department').then(
    function (response) {
        $scope.departments = response.data;
    },
    function (response) {
        toaster.pop('error', "Error", "An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
);

$http.get('/api/getTravelerInformation', { params: { id: $routeParams.userKey } }).then(
   function (response) {
       $scope.request = response.data;
       $scope.travelerDepartment = underscoreService.findWhere($scope.departments, { Id: $scope.request.TravelerDepartmentId });
   },
    function (response) {
        toaster.pop('error', "Error", "An unexpected error occurred.");
    }
);
```

Angular Template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Department</label>
    <div class="left-inner-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i>
        <select ng-model="travelerDepartment"
                ng-options="department.Name for department in departments track by department.Id"
                ng-init="request.TravelerDepartmentId = travelerDepartment.Id"
                ng-change="request.TravelerDepartmentId = travelerDepartment.Id"
                class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "track by" so that the objects can be compared correctly. Otherwise Angular will use the native js way of comparing objects.

So your example code would change to -

```
    <select ng-options="size.code as size.name
 for size in sizes track by size.code" 
ng-model="item.size.code"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**AngularJS's Filter** worked out for me.

Assuming the `code/id` is *unique*, we can filter out that particular object with AngularJS's `filter` and work with the selected objects properties. Considering the example above:

```
<select ng-options="size.code as size.name for size in sizes" 
        ng-model="item.size.code" 
        ng-change="update(MAGIC_THING); search.code = item.size.code">
</select>

<!-- OUTSIDE THE SELECT BOX -->

<h1 ng-repeat="size in sizes | filter:search:true"
    ng-init="search.code = item.size.code">
  {{size.name}}
</h1>
```

Now, there are **3 important aspects to this**:

1. `ng-init="search.code = item.size.code"` - on initializing `h1` element outside `select` box, set the filter query to the *selected option*.
2. `ng-change="update(MAGIC_THING); search.code = item.size.code"` - when you change the select input, we'll run one more line which will set the "search" query to the currently selected `item.size.code`.
3. `filter:search:true` - Pass `true` to filter to enable *strict matching*.

That's it.  If the `size.code` is *uniqueID*, we'll have only one `h1` element with the text of `size.name`.

I've tested this in my project and it works.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest way to get a value from an angular select options list (other than The Id or Text).
Assuming you have a Product Select like this on your page :

```
<select ng-model="data.ProductId"
        ng-options="product.Id as product.Name for product in productsList"
        ng-change="onSelectChange()">
</select>
```

Then in Your Controller set the callback function like so:

```
    $scope.onSelectChange = function () {
        var filteredData = $scope.productsList.filter(function (response) {
            return response.Id === $scope.data.ProductId;
        })
        console.log(filteredData[0].ProductColor);
    }
```

**Simply Explained:** Since the ng-change event does not recognize the option items in the select, we are using the ngModel to filter out the selected Item from the options list loaded in the controller.

Furthermore, since the event is fired before the ngModel is really updated, you might get undesirable results, So a better way would be to add a timeout :

```
        $scope.onSelectChange = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
            var filteredData = $scope.productsList.filter(function (response) {
                return response.Id === $scope.data.ProductId;
            })
            console.log(filteredData[0].ProductColor);
            }, 100);
        };
```