# Angularjs: How do I get the item in a list when using ngChange?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to get the item that just changed in this small example, is there some kind of context I should use? I hoped it would be as simple as just referring to $this, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function myController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      { id: 1, name: "First" },
      { id: 2, name: "Second" },
      { id: 3, name: "Third" }
    ];

    $scope.test = function() {
        // How do I get the object in the list related to the change i did?
        // I.e. "{ id: 2, name: "Second" }" for the second item.
    };
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-change="test()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change)

Comment: How about ng-change="test(item)"

Comment: @MichaelLo thanks! I cant believe i missed that! Sorry for the stupid question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/80/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-change="test(item.name)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      { id: 1, name: "First" },
      { id: 2, name: "Second" },
      { id: 3, name: "Third" }
    ];

    $scope.test = function(item) {
        alert(item);
    };
});
```

Comment: I saw the comment from @MichaelLo as well. Thanks to both of you! Can't believe I missed that... :)

Comment: I can't upvote, to low rep (this was my first question). I can only accept it as answered!