# Angular JS - ng-click not working in select option [Chrome]

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have a `select option` element in order to change the way to sort an ordered list. Each time I select a different option it fires an `ng-click`

```
 <select>
     <option ng-click="sortType = ['-grade','-year']">Grade</a>
     <option ng-click="sortType = ['-year','-grade']">Year</a>
     <option ng-click="sortType = 'student'">Name</a>
</select>
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:sortType">{{name.student}} from {{name.year}}th year gets a {{name.grade}}</li>
</ul>
```

That changes the `$scope` I use to indicate the criteria to order the list

```
$scope.sortType = ['-grade','-year'];
```

The problem is that while in Firefox this is working perfectly, in Chrome the `ng-click` just doesn't fire.

This question [is similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367819/ng-click-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-in-firefox), but in my case I cannot use a `ng-options`. This bug is also discussed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051345/select-options-through-ng-click-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser-using-angularjs#answer-29707282), but it seems that they link it to a bug that is already marked as solved in Chrome.

Any alternative way to make this work in Chrome is welcome. You can [check the Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9BWFtisMAPOKnwYjEC1?p=preview).

Comment: Try ngChange https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select `ngChange` (optional) string  Angular expression to be executed when selected option(s) changes due to user interaction with the select element. `<select ng-model="string"  [ng-change="string"]   [ng-options="string"]> </select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-model` in combination with `value` instead. In this case on change, the value will be assigned to `sortType` and it should work in all browsers(supported by AngularJS), I've tested in latest Chrome and Firefox.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [{student: 'John', year: 2015, grade: 'bachelor'}, {student: 'Arnold', year: 2016, grade: 'magister'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<select ng-model="sortType">
     <option value="['-grade','-year']">Grade</a>
     <option value="sortType = ['-year','-grade']">Year</a>
     <option value="sortType = 'student'">Name</a>
</select>
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:sortType">{{name.student}} from {{name.year}}th year gets a {{name.grade}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is also [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rLU4hVRMnS5aGfuW8wiH?p=preview)