# How to use AngularJS to update an object array based on a selection change

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have two dynamic object arrays. One for colors, one for buses. The goal is to assign a color to a bus. So, using ng-repeat the code create selects for each color, then using ng-change to call a the updatebus function, passing in the color id. But, it doesn't work. The color id is always undefined.

How can I assign the color to the bus with two arrays? What am I doing wrong?

I tried looking at this answer: [getting the ng-object selected with ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqgTWNhKOeKDgS5w4pNL?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - combining two arrays</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', id:'a'},
      {name:'white', id:'b'},
      {name:'red', id:'c'},
      {name:'blue', id:'d'},
      {name:'yellow', id:'e'}
    ];

    $scope.buses = [
      {name:'bus 1', colorid:''},
      {name:'bus 2', colorid:''}
    ];

    $scope.theBus = $scope.buses[1]; // red

    $scope.updatebus = function(bus, id){
      //alert(id); // undefined
      $scope.theBus = bus;
      bus.cid = id;
    };
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">

<p>
  Bus Color:
  <div ng-repeat="bus in buses">
  {{bus.name}} 
    <select ng-model="myColor" 
    ng-options="color.name for color in colors" 
    ng-change="updatebus(bus, color.id)">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
    </select>
    <p>
  </div>
  <div>
    the bus "{{theBus.name}}" has color id "{{theBus.colorid}}"
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The ng-change method is not part of the "repeat" in ng-options.  It's defined once, and doesn't have a 'color' variable.

Comment: be consistent with your property names. You have `bus.cid = id` but you have `colorid` as the property name in the `buses` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems here:

- You had a typo: `bus.cid = id;`
- And your expression in `ng-change` didn't make any sense: `updatebus(bus, color.id)`. `color`? Which `color`? There's a whole bunch of them.

One way to fix this:

```
bus.colorid = id;
```

```
<select ng-model="myColor" 
ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in colors" 
ng-change="updatebus(bus, myColor)">
```

Updated Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/571TY2dC8cmLSPA7AAIv?p=preview

Or just bind your select right to `bus.colorid` (I would say this is actually the better approach as it will allow the dropdown to show the correct value if your buses have initial color values):

```
<select ng-model="bus.colorid" 
ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in colors" 
ng-change="updatebus(bus)">
```

```
$scope.updatebus = function(bus){
  //alert(bus.name); // undefined
  $scope.theBus = bus;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, the second select bound to `bus.colorid` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the color of the `bus` from your `ng-repeat` as the `ng-model` of your `select`. That way you have full access to the selected color for each bus.

```
<select ng-model="bus.color" 
    ng-options="color.name for color in colors" 
    ng-change="updatebus(bus)">
```

All the assignments are done in the html bindings, the `ng-change` remains only for display purposes.

Please have a look, I made some minor changes in order to make it work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SoBUK61121VrqT31Jihj?p=preview

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't think you want color.id in the updatebus call.  'color' doesn't exist on that scope.

Comment: Thanks, this did help, but yes, I don't want there to be `bus.color`.