# How make related selects in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have two select list HTML.
How I can make easy them related? I mean when I select option from first select, some options from second select are shown to hidden?
Selects lists HTML created by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways using angular. One way is to use the ng-change:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="item in items1" ng-change="update(selectedItem1)"></select>
```

and then have the update(selectedItem1) function update your items2 list. And vice versa for your items2 drop down.

```
$scope.update = function(selectedItem1) {
   $scope.items2 = // logic to filter items 2 based on selectedItem1
}

<select ng-model="selectedItem2" ng-options="item in items2" ng-change="updateSet1(selectedItem2)"></select>
```

Alternatively, you could use a $watch function, to watch selectedItem1 and update items2 list in this function.

If you need to use a custom filter, see here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

```
angular.module('myModule', []).filter('items2', function() {
  return function(selectedItem1, items2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items2.length; i++) {
       // return items you want
    }
  };
});
```

Then in your controller, include this filter as dependency items2Filter by appending Filter and you can update $scope.items2 like so:

```
$scope.items2 = items2Filter($scope.selectedItem1, $scope.items2);
```

Comment: Mark Rajcok's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change
except pass in the selected item as a parameter and update the second list in the update function.

Comment: Perhaps you could give more information on how you want to filter the items. You may want to use a custom filter to do this or perhaps using lodash will be possible

Comment: Do you follow this answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I will try and response here. Just question in this: `ng-options="item in items2"` I need create `items2` object with all values of select list?

Comment: Yes, this should be your array of values

Comment: Can I do it without array options in JS, if I have select list at page?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the generated HTML that you are working with - can you alter the html?