# Cascading Dropdown List - Multi Direction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, filter, cascading

First of all I am quiet new to AngularJS and I have seen several implementations of cascading dropdown lists yet they are not functioning the way I want and/or I dont know how to modify/extend them to do what I want.

Maybe you can point me to right direction or post an example. I believe it would be useful for many people.

Required Functionality: Multiple Dropdown lists with relational data in them. On selected item changed update all other dropdowns based on selection.

Example 1: 3 dropdowns. 1st one with colleges, 2nd with majors and 3rd with degrees.

In most examples when college is selected majors in that college is displayed then when major is selected degrees are shown. What I want is when major is selected filter colleges or when PHD is selected from 3rd drop down remove all colleges without PHD programs or any major without a PHD degree.

Example 2: Brand (BMW, Audi, Mercedes etc.), Style (Convertable, Sedan, Minivan etc.), Price Range(10k-20k, 20k-30k, 30k-50k etc.)

When Brand is chosen show its styles and price ranges.
When Style is chosen show brands that have chosen style and remove price ranges that have no item falling in that range.
When Price is chosen show brands and styles that fall in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Is this link helpful ?

http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/

```
function AjaxCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = ['usa', 'canada', 'mexico', 'france'];
    $scope.$watch('country', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.cities = ['Los Angeles', 'San Francisco'];
    });
    $scope.$watch('city', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.suburbs = ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'];
    });
}

function StaticCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = {
        'usa': {
            'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
            'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
        },
        'canada': {
            'People dont live here': ['igloo', 'cave']
        }
    };
}
```

And there is another way using the ng-change attr:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14386972/3202657

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have seen examples like this. Couple of differences I am looking for example:

1- All drop downs should be enabled all times.

2- Assume first dropdown is Apple, Asus, Lenovo etc. and second one is Laptop, Desktop, Tablet etc. and third one is price range like 250-500, 500-750 and 750+. I want to be able to choose Desktop to filter out companies that does not have any Desktop computer and also rule out price ranges to which no Desktop computer falls in.