# Papulate Dropdown options on select using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i populate options dynamically in select drop-down on click.
i want to fetch some data from backend on clicking select box.

```
`ng-options="type.shorthand as type.name for type in allTypes"`
```

i want to store value in `allTypes` when i click on select box to list dropdown.

Comment: You can use `ng-click` inside `ng-click` call one function to fetch data from backend and push the same data to `allTypes`. make sure `allTypes` should be initialized as empty array.

Comment: This question is answered in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14386972/2115672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its generally a good idea to `fetch` the values for drop-down before hand

```
<select ng-model="yourFormModel.yourAttributeName" 
        ng-options="type.shorthand as type.name for type in allTypes" 
        ng-init="fetchTypes()"></select>
```

Somewhere in your controller code.

```
$scope.fetchTypes = function(){
   $http.get('/path/to/types')
        .then(function(data){
             $scope.allTypes = data;
         });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller

$scope.dropDownVals = "";
getDataForDropDown();

just on the load of the page you can call a factory/service function from the controller which makes the http request to the server side code to get the json object response and then assign it

in services/factory function
http get call to the server side code
.then(function(data){
$scope.dropDownVals = data.requiredField;

});

Thank you