# change function need to run after select option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my code their is one drop downlist and if you write something in that input field it will show you the datalist if that word is available....

My problem is i want to run the change function when i select the item from the list not when i entered some thing in the input field....
but still i need the datalist when i entered some thing in the input field...

http://jsfiddle.net/4dGxn/148/

**html**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="srch" list="datalist1" id="exampleInputName2 srch" placeholder="author" ng-model="author_name" ng-change="changeFun()">
  <datalist id="datalist1">
    <option ng-repeat="author in authors" value="{{author}}">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

**angular**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.authors = ["author1", "author2", "author3", "author4", "author5"];

    $scope.changeFun = function(){
    console.log("hello i am change function")
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I think this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change

Comment: @Harry with select i can solve the problem... but i need to solve with input because i need both functionality text box and data list together.