# Getting the object selected with ng-change when dropDown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

list of projects in form of {"id": *some num*, "name": *some name* }

get by viewBag

```
$scope.projects = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.vbProjects));
```

My drop down menu:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-1">Project</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="project" required>
                        <option ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy : 'name'" value="{{project.id}}">{{project.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            project: {{project}}
            project.id: {{project.id}}
            project.name: {{project.name}}
```

How I fill the data:

```
$scope.project = {"id":$scope.someObject.ProjectNameId ,"name":$scope.someObject.ProjectNameName};
```

And the result:

> project: {"id":18,"name":"someName"}  project.id: 18  project.name:
>   someName

And yet in the dropDown it dosent write it to me.

I tried to use this page:
[getting the ng-object selected with ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change)

But with no help.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) rather than ng-repeat... like this.

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="project" required
   ng-options="project as project.name for project in projects">
 </select>
```

Read more on [select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive