# Remove active class from dropdown in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular2-template

I want to remove 'active' class from dropdown on document click and as soon as an option is selected. I'm able to achieve removing it on document click but I'm stuck on how to remove it on selecting an option.

TS :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        const elem = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('select');
        const option_elem = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('option');
        this.renderer.listen(document.body, 'click', (event) => {
            if (event.target == elem) {
                this.addClass(elem, 'active');
            }
            else {
                this.removeClass(elem, 'active');
            }
        });

        for(var i=0; i<=option_elem.length; i++){
             this.renderer.listen(option_elem, 'click', (event) => {
                 this.removeClass(elem,'active');
             });
         }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="dropdown">                
    <select class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" name="menu" id="menu">
         <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of selectOption" [value]="item.value"> {{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should use native angular biding instead of listening to clicks. Use `click()` and `change()` methods instead, here is an example to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change

Comment: Firstly, you aren't using the i key in your for loop. Second, Consider using angular directives like [class.active]. Third, try to use let instead of var for block scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not handle adding and removing classes imperatively. Let the angular do the work for you and use data bindings. Use `[class.active]` binding combined with `[(ngModel)]` on the select.

component.html

```
<div class="dropdown">                
  <select class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" name="menu" id="menu" [(ngModel)]="selected" [class.active]="selected === null">
    <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of selectOption" [value]="item.value"> {{item.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
selected = null;
```

Comment: But this will add active class to option and I dont want that... I want active class to be added to select and then when an option is selected, active class should be removed..

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `option_element` into `option_element[i]`, because option_element is an array here.

```
for(var i=0; i<=option_elem.length; i++){
  this.renderer.listen(option_elem[i], 'click', (event) => {
     this.removeClass(elem,'active');
  });
}
```